# .htaccess conflict in rules

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url, errordocument

I am not very familiar with .htaccess, but have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^centurion/programme-(.*).php$ ./centurion/programme.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^klerksdorp/programme-(.*).php$ ./klerksdorp/programme.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^tygervalley/programme-(.*).php$ ./tygervalley/programme.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^rustenburg/programme-(.*).php$ ./rustenburg/programme.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^witbank/programme-(.*).php$ ./witbank/programme.php?cid=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The code above basically make the url's "friendly" by changing the url's to something more descriptive for dynamic pages and removing the .php extentions of the "static" pages.

This all works perfect. But now I need to redirect error/file not found pages as well. I tried adding the following (with relative paths and absolute paths):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

But when I enter an incorrect url (in the browser), I still get "file not found" error (not the redirected page).

When I add the following, all the pages redirect to the index.php page:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

When I have only the following code in my .htaccess file, the incorrect url's redirect as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

But then, obviously, non of my "friendly" url rules work.

How can I have both the "friendly" url rules as well as the incorrect url redirects work together?

Comment: Give a proper example of an “incorrect” URL.

Comment: It can be http://example.com/sample.php (where there is no sample.php file) or something like http://example.com/programme-pga-golf (which is an old link and the programme is no longer offered)

Comment: Try and make that last condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` - if what was requested exists as a file, when the suffix `.php` gets appended, only then rewrite it to that.

Comment: @04FS Thanks. As far as I can tell changing that condition adds the .php extention at the end of my "friendly" url's, eg. example.com/programme-accounting now becomes example.com/programme-accounting.php. This is not solving my problem.

Comment: There is no external redirect, so I don’t see how that would be possible.